# glDrawArrays modify attribute address

Tags: opengl

Will glDrawArrays modify glVertexAttribPointer addresses?

I stumbled up onto this problem when I was trying to cache glVertexAttribPointer calls, and if I don't reapply the glVertexAttribPointer call after each glDrawArrays I get a Access Violation Exception. This is the normal behavior or maybe a driver bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will glDrawArrays modify glVertexAttribPointer addresses?

**No.**

> I stumbled up onto this problem when I was trying to cache glVertexAttribPointer calls

Please explain (ideally show source code) how you did implement this "caching".

Comment: The caching is pretty simple it just checks if the last used "vertex declaration" was himself, the code: https://gist.github.com/greenboxal/e2872b85160bd286cd78
This code works perfectly if I reapply(comment that first if) it every frame before glDrawArrays.
baseAddress is always 0 as I'm using VBOs.

Comment: @greenboxal: Can you warrant that no other part of the program does change the glVertexAttribPointer? Honestly: This kind of "optimization" is a microoptimization not worth its effort. More importantly, well written OpenGL drivers perform the very same check as you do, so you gain nothing, but since your program and the OpenGL driver are separated by a tight API the driver can warrant that this check is valid.

Comment: I see, I'll accept your answer and remove that if, just one more thing, there is any place on OpenGL that this kind of optimization is worth? Textures, Buffers, etc...

Comment: In case of a identity state transistion (i.e. OpenGL state before and after is identical) such kind of state tracking will gain little to nothing. However minimizing state transistions that alter the state is worthwile if it affects a state expensive to switch. Most importantly Textures and Shader Programs. Ideally sort/queue the order in which geometry is rendered by texture and shader so that a minimal number of texture and shader switches is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

An access violation happens when your vertex attribute pointer goes beyond the memory range of the buffer you're reading from.

How are you caching these calls? If you don't disable a vertex attrib array, the previously set info will still be there and will still try to read from the new VBO.